# Uncertainty when calculating volume of a rectangular block

Tags: numerical-methods, volume

I'm trying to determine the uncertainty in volume  , $ V = b \cdot h \cdot l$ ,  of a rectangular block with the following measurements,

$$ b \quad=\quad 2 \pm 0.1 $$
$$ h \quad=\quad 2 \pm 0.2 $$
$$ l \quad=\quad 2 \pm 0.3 $$

I thought that the uncertainty is given by

$$ \delta_{volume} \quad=\quad {V}_{max} - {V} $$

And therefore

$$ V \quad=\quad b \cdot h \cdot l \quad=\quad 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \quad=\quad 8 $$
$$ V_{max} \quad=\quad 2.1 \cdot 2.2 \cdot 2.3 \quad=\quad 10.626 $$

Subtracting those we get
$$ \longrightarrow \quad \delta_{volume} \quad=\quad {V}_{max} - {V} \quad=\quad 10.626 - 8 \quad=\quad 2.626 $$

But the answer is apparently wrong, the answer should be $\frac{4}{10} \sqrt{14} $  .  I don't even know where the square root comes from! Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a size $A(x, y, z)$ calculated with more basic sizes $x, y, z$, which have uncertainties $\Delta x, \Delta y, \Delta z$ respectively, we know that the uncertainty in $A$ is:
$$\Delta A = \sqrt{(\frac{\partial A}{\partial x}\cdot \Delta x)^2 + (\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}\cdot \Delta y)^2 + (\frac{\partial A}{\partial z}\cdot \Delta z)^2}$$
Here, you have $V(b, h, l)$, with known uncertainties $0.1, 0.2, 0.3$, so:
$$\Delta V = \sqrt{(bh\Delta l)^2 +(hl\Delta b)^2+(bl \Delta h)^2}$$
Plugging in your values gives:
$$\Delta V= \sqrt{(4\cdot 0.3)^2 +(4\cdot 0.1)^2+(4\cdot 0.2)^2}=0.4\sqrt{3^2+1^2+2^2}=0.4\sqrt{14}$$

Which is exactly the answer.
Note: this formula can be extended to any amount of "basic" variables.

Comment: Importantly, this formula (propagation of uncertainty) is used when the errors are statistical in nature. Thus, you plug in standard deviations and get standard deviations out. This does not exactly fit the measurement of a rectangular block, as there, the uncertainties are actually bounds on possible values (the distribution is rectangular, not Gaussian). You plug in values that are *certain* (the dimensions actually cannot be more wrong), but get out only a statistical uncertainty estimate (which could underestimate the actual error). OP's method gives the correct worst case scenario.